# Apache mod_rewrite rules don't work with dynamic virtual host and php-fpm

Tags: apache2, php, php-fpm, mod-rewrite, fastcgi

I've created a dynamic virtual host using this configuration file:

```xml
UseCanonicalName Off
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName %1.dev
    ServerAlias *.%1.dev

    ServerAdmin daniel@localhost
    VirtualDocumentRoot /home/daniel/public_html/%1

    LogLevel error rewrite:trace8 proxy:trace2

    ErrorLog /home/daniel/public_html/error.log
    CustomLog /home/daniel/public_html/access.log combined

    <Directory ~ "/home/daniel/public_html/.*">
        Options Indexes FollowSymlinks Multiviews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
        RewriteEngine On

        <FilesMatch "\.php$">
            SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost:9000"
        </FilesMatch>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This works fine with php scripts, but I can't make it work with SEF URLs such as those used by WordPress (e.g. http//mysite.dev/blog return 404).

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

To make that work you need to enable rewrite module in Apache.

See this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04

After you have the module you will need something like this (wordpress example):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

This should be placed in either .htacccess file or vhost file.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. This is what I currently have in my .htaccess file:

    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
    # END WordPress

The problem is that this seems to be telling php-fpm to look for the php script in the /var/www/html directory (Apache's global DOCUMENT_ROOT), instead of /home/daniel/public_html/my-wp-site

Answer (score 0):

Check your Apache config file and enable rewrite for all.

Open terminal and write: nano `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Find these lines and write exactly this code :

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Change `AllowOverride none` to `AllowOverride All`.